# Finding the intersections of each attributes in two list

Tags: python, list

I am looking for an alternative method of finding the intersection of the items in the list without zipping both list.

Here's the zip method that works:

```
>>> list1= [('red', 'black'), ('orange', 'grapes'), ('cat', 'dog')]
>>> list2= [('blue', 'red'), ('orange', 'apple'), ('dog', 'mouse')]
>>> _zip=zip(list1,list2)
>>> [set(x[0])& set(x[1]) for x in _zip]
[set(['red']), set(['orange']), set(['dog'])]
```

Is there a way to avoid using zip? as zip stores data in memory, and I do not want that given how large my data-set is.

**I would like the final output to be something like a generator that does not consume memory.**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [itertools.izip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) instead of zip. `itertools.izip` creates the iterator instead of list.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

```
[set(x) & set(list2[i]) for i, x in enumerate(list1)]
```

or use `izip` from `itertools` instead of `zip`